# How to fetch all the records using the like query in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to fetch all the records whose employeeId starts with 123.For this, I thought of using like query with regex.

```
Sample Records in MongoDB:
============================
{name:"XYZ",employeeID : 123456}
{name:"ABC",employeeID : 123789}
{name:"DEF",employeeID : 214356}
```

After query, it should retrieve only first two records.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: employeeId field is a number

Comment: `/^123/` basically, ^ means start of string, followed by 123. meaning it'll grab anything starting with 123

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Write Query like this

db.getCollection('employee').find({ $where: "/^123.*/.test(this.employeeID)" })

Result :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ab13f239d775c5cc667"),
    "name" : "XYZ",
    "employeeID" : 123456
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ab13f239d775c5cc668"),
    "name" : "ABC",
    "employeeID" : 123789
}
```

Comment: I can use the below query if employeeID is a String
db.col.find({employeeID:/123/}) . But how can I use the same query if employeeID is a number

Comment: Is BasicQuery like BasicDBObject ?

Comment: Hi Satish, it is working only with String not with number as an employeeId

Comment: Oops ,yup i forgot regex works with string in mongo db also .No worry here is another option try this { $where: "/^123.*/.test(this.employeeID)" }  . I just tested and this works for me

Comment: What is test here? Can u please edit the entire code

Comment: Hey i just tried with this query db.getCollection('message').find({ $where: "/^1.*/.test(this.unReadMessagesCount)" }) where unReadMessagesCount is integer . test is function to tell mongo db what you want to test against the value of regex.

Comment: By using the above query,it is retrieving all the 3 documents,because all the 3 documents contains 123 digits.I just want the documents which start with 123.so that only first two documents gets fetched

Comment: Hey I don't know  how your are trying . i just tried the same and its giving me exact result what you want. See

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

db.getCollection('test').find({ employeeID: { $regex: /^123.*$/ } })